# why "Users: watch" Google Api Giving backend error?

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, google-api-js-client

> Error:   { error: { errors: [Array], code: 500, message: 'Backend Error' } } }

My code

```
var options = {

  auth:auth,
  userId: 'me',
  resource: {
      labelIds: ['INBOX'],
      topicName: 'projects/testwatch-200121/topics/jeet'
  }
};

gmail.users.watch(options, function (err, res) {

  if (err) {
      console.log(err.response)
      return;
  }
  console.log(res)
});
```